# Reading mail content from m365 group mailbox

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks, microsoft-graph-mail, exchange-online

I'm developing a solution in which I want to react on incoming mails from a group mailbox (not a shared mailbox) and store the content of the mail, including attachments, in a SharePoint library.

I have a webhook subscribing the group mailbox and triggers an Azure Function. In the Azure Function we can retrieve attachments from the post-endpoint using the Graph API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/conversations/{conversation-id}/threads/{thread-id}/posts/{post-id}/attachments
```

However, we do not have access to the mail itself through the Graph API. The body of the post contains only a snippet of the mail forwarded to the group mailbox. It appears that only the last part of the mail is included and the rest of the conversation history is omitted.

Another approach considered was forwarding the mail (post) to a service account for processing. This approach works in principle since we can retrieve the email content from a regular mailbox using the Graph API. However, this option is not feasible for the customer.

Another attempted approach was processing it through a Power Automate Flow. However, we face the same limitations here as well. We do not have access to the full email content.

The solution must also support dragging and dropping the mail from the user's mailbox to the group mailbox via Outlook.

Can anyone provide a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after any specific properties on the Message? the Post strongly typed objects are a pretty limited in what properties you can display but they allow you to specify singleValueExtendedProperties so you can always get the underlying exchange extended property (on the message) eg to get the Subject via the extended property you can use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/../threads/A...A=?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x0037')
```

To get the HTMLBody you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaghtml-canonical-property this will return the body base64 encoded

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/../threads/A...A=?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Binary 0x1013')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried your example and received the subject of the mail. However, I need the entire body of the Message. Is that possible?

Comment: It seems that the body properties do undergo some business rules processing on the backend to extract just the last reply. If you want to get the full body from the Post Pr_Html seems to be have been excluded from that processing and works okay (You just need to decode it from base64) added an example that work for me above

Comment: Thanks for your response! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Is it also possible to retrieve the original mail as file (for saving in a SharePoint library) and the recipient's mail adress? I was only able to identify the display name of the recipient.